# Unreachable code using returns in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I´ve got the following function:

```
renderButtons(status) {
    
    if(status === 'PENDING') {
      return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Button
            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 5, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor: '#013773',
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width-250}}
            title='Retirar' 
            />
          <Button
            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 25, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'grey',
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width-250}}
            title='Cancelar' 
            />
        </View>);
    }
    else {
      return     
        ( <Button
            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
            title='Cancelar' 
            />);
    }
    
}
```

Turns out the second returns is pointed out by VisualStudioCode as unreachable. I don't really know what's happening it seems so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
return     
        ( <Button
            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
            title='Cancelar' 
            />);
```

to

```
 return  ( <Button
            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
            title='Cancelar' 
            />);
```

If return is in a separate line it wont return the components instead it'll just return nothing and the next set of lines wont be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference between `getValueOne` and `getValueTwo` in the below examples. You should be very cautious when returning from functions.

```js
const getValueOne = () => {
  return {
    x: 10
  }
}

console.log(getValueOne())

const getValueTwo = () => {
  return 
  { x: 10 }
}

console.log(getValueTwo())
```

In the above example in `getValueTwo`, even though `return` & `{ x: 10 }` is there but javascript understands them as different statements, so `undefined` will be returned.

So it'll be interpreted as like below

```
return;
{x: 10};
```

So in your code also, in else part always `undefined` is being returned.
Change it like below

```
return (<Button
            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
            title='Cancelar' 
            />);
    }
```

Hope this helps.